# android crooked text

Tags: android

I have a question, is it possible to make text at an angle? For example:

[image]

Any ideas how I do this?

Comment: Lots of downvotes but no comments, not very helpful

Answer (score 5):

Use custom font. Write your text using that font on canvas. Rotate canvas.

Answer (score 0):

Dirty way : JQuery rotate plugin (http://code.google.com/p/jqueryrotate/).

Nice but unsupported in ie and most old browsers, css3 :

```
div {
transform:rotate(7deg);
-ms-transform:rotate(7deg); /* IE 9 */
-moz-transform:rotate(7deg); /* Firefox */
-webkit-transform:rotate(7deg); /* Safari and Chrome */
-o-transform:rotate(7deg); /* Opera */
}
```